Cannot use fileinput.input as stdin in subprocess.run
I was under the impression that fileinput.input([path_1, path2, ...]) is basically interchangeable with open(path_1) except that the former concatenates the contents of all the files given. However, fileinput.input behaves differently when passed as stdin to subprocess.run. That is, subprocess.run just hangs and doesn't read anything from the file(s) at all.
Here's an example:
example.py:
import fileinput
import subprocess
import sys

idle_path = sys.exec_prefix + "/bin/idle3"
paths = [idle_path]

with fileinput.input(paths) as combined_file:
# with open(idle_path) as combined_file:
    subprocess.run(["cat"], stdin=combined_file)


Calling the above e.g. in the console with python example.py does not finish.
With open instead of fileinput.input it works and produces the contents of /bin/idle3 as expected:
$ python example.py
#!/home/me/mambaforge/envs/testenv/bin/python3.12

from idlelib.pyshell import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

What's going on there? How can I pipe the combined content of multiple files to any command I want to use with subprocess.run?
I see this on Python 3.12, not sure if it makes any difference. The command I'm actually trying to run is not cat but subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "cantools", "plot", "/path/to/vehicle.dbc"], stdin=combined_candumps). (see cantools docs). Running the whole thing in the shell isn't really an option because I want to get some of the arguments from a GUI to be written in Python. While cantools is written in Python, it has a shell-only API and no documented Python interface. That's the reason for the roundtrip via subprocess.run.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run :

stdin, stdout and stderr [...] Valid values are [...] an existing file object with a valid file descriptor.

fileinput.input is a python object, it doesn't have a file descriptor.

How can I pipe the combined content of multiple files to any command I want to use with subprocess.run?

You would create a pipe to create a file descriptor, asynchronously write to the pipe and let the process read it. Something along, untested, written here:
def cat(paths, file):
   with fileinput.input(paths) as combined_file:
      for line in combined_file:
         print(line, file=file)

r, w = os.pipe()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: cat(paths, os.fdopen(w))).start()
subprocess.run(["cat"], stdin=r)

Or just shutil.copyfileobj, should be just:
threading.Thread(target=lambda: shutil.copyfileobj(paths, os.fdopen(w))).start()
subprocess.run(["cat"], stdin=r)


combined_file does have a file descriptor but it is set to -1 (not valid) until you start reading: I guess that's why my cantools example worked when I discarded the first line with combined_file.readline() before subprocess.run(...). However that hack doesn't work with cat for some reason.

I do not understand. It doesn't have a file descriptor. It returns -1, which exactly means, that it doesn't have a file descriptor. There is no file descriptor that can refer to multiple files. In shell you would cat file1 file2 etc - | program to concatenate multiple files into a file descriptor - this is what you are trying to implement in python, where program is cat.  I do not understand the rest of the comment. When I have the time maybe today, I'll try to test the presented code.

I also just realized that I can just call cat from Python. I was just puzzled why fileinput wouldn't work. You pointed me in the right direction.

I doubt this approach can match the performance of cat or type. Just scanning for all the line endings seems like a lot of unnecessary work for the CPU. A solution that is fast and cross-platform would be sweet!

I do not understand. I doubt this approach What approuch? Just scanning for all the line There is shutil.copyfileobj if you do not want to iterate over lines for line in combined_file:. If your intention is (extreme) speed, I doubt python is a solution - consider rust, go, C, C++. cat itself is not cross-platform (thinking of windows). Is this XY question? If you want speed, why not just call cat with the filenames?

With "this approach" I'm referring to the specific code above that iterates line-by-line. cat was not the best example for the MCVE - I didn't think of the Windows requirement then. I use cantools plot with many megabytes of input files which works on Linux and Windows after pip install cantools. I want speed and the code needs to work on Linux and Windows. My answer seems good enough - I'm just not particularly happy with having the platform-dependent strategy fork (cat on Unix or type on Windows).

As KamilCuk points out, subprocess.run requires a file object with a valid file descriptor. In the source code of subprocess.py it looks like this file descriptor must also be static. While the context manager created with fileinput.input provides a file descriptor, it is not always valid (it's -1 at the start, between files and at the end), and it changes since every file has its own file descriptor.
Therefore, it is complicated to solve this issue with fileinput in Python. It's easier to just use cat in another subprocess for combining the files:
import fileinput
import subprocess
import sys

idle_path = sys.exec_prefix + "/bin/idle3"
doc_path = sys.exec_prefix + "/bin/pydoc"
paths = [idle_path, doc_path]

combined = subprocess.Popen(["cat"] + paths, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.run(["cat"], stdin=combined.stdout)
combined.wait()

The code above is adapted from another answer on Stackoverflow.
This approach has the following limitations:

cat - or really, any program - is inherently limited in how long the list of file name arguments can be (just over 25000 on my machine); see Bash command line and input limit
cat is not available on every system. Notably, there is no such command on Windows. On Windows, one can use ["cmd", "/c", "type"] (see this answer) instead of ["cat"] to concatenate files.

The second cat in the example code above can be any shell command. I just use cat here because that's what I chose for my MCVE in the question. For cantools, code for Windows and Unix would be:
cat = ["cmd", "/c", "type"] if sys.platform == "win32" else ["cat"]
combined_candumps = subprocess.Popen(cat + paths, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.run(
    [sys.executable, "-m", "cantools", "plot", "/path/to/vehicle.dbc"],
    stdin=combined_candumps.stdout
)
combined_candumps.wait()


import fileinput
import subprocess

# Read the input data
input_data = ''.join(fileinput.input())

# Run the subprocess with the input data
result = subprocess.run(['your_command', 'arg1', 'arg2'],
input = input_data, text=True, capture_output=True)

# Print the output of the subprocess
print(result.stdout)

Read the input data using fileinput.input.
Pass the read data to subprocess.run using the input parameter.
In this example, fileinput.input() reads the input data from the specified files or standard input. The data is then joined into a single string and passed to subprocess.run via the input parameter.
Make sure to replace 'your_command', 'arg1', 'arg2' with the actual command and arguments you want to run.
If you need more specific help, please provide more details about the command you're trying to run and the context in which you're using fileinput.input

Perhaps I'm restating the obvious, but the OP clearly wanted to avoid reading all the input into memory. (Not my downvote, though.)
